# jquery combining chaining when done when done and so on ... when then

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an structure like below that I need to be executed in order:

```
var task1, task2, task3, last;

initialize = $.when(function(){ ...initializing... }).done(function(){ ..initialization completed.. });

task1 = initialize.when(function(){ ..doing task1.. }).done(function(){ ..task1 completed.. });

task2 = task1.when(function(){ ..doing task2.. }).done(function(){ ..task2 completed.. });

task3 = task2.when(function(){ ..doing task3.. }).done(function(){ ..task3 completed.. });

last  = task3.when(function(){ ..doing last.. }).then(function(){ ..last completed.. });
```

how to do this with jQuery-1.10.2?

Considering above example the console output would be:

```
initializing
initialization completed
doing task1
task1 completed
doing task2
task2 completed
doing task3
task3 completed
doing last
last completed
```

Comment: .then would make your code much cleaner, but you've hidden so much of your code that i can't effectively give you an example. `initialize().then(doTask1).then(doTask2).then(doTask3)`

Comment: @KevinB see here more detailed: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/unwinding-promises-and-their-handlers-asp-net-mvc-and-jquery

Answer (score 0):

When working with asynchronous tasks that need to be executed in order you can wrapp them with [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and chain them using [`deffered.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/):

```
function init() {
    console.log("initializing");
}

function doTask1() { 
    var d = $.Deferred(); 
    console.log("synchronous part of task 1"); 
    setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log("asynchronous part of task 1"); 
        d.resolve() }, 5000); 
    return d;
}

function doTask2(resFromTask1) {
    var d = $.Deferred(); 
    console.log("task2");
    setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log("asynchronous part of task 2"); 
        d.resolve() }, 5000); 

    return d;
}

function doLast() {
    console.log("last task");
}

$.when(init()).then(doTask1).then(doTask2).done(doLast);
```

Note that the `doLast` function get's called when the deffered returned from `doTask2` is resolved. So if for instance we wanted to run a synchronous function after `doTask1` but before `doTask2` it would need to be added like this:

```
$.when(init()).then(doTask1).done(function() { 
       console.log("new synchronous function"); 
   }).then(doTask2).done(doLast);
```

Now both the `doTask2` and the anonymous function are run when `doTask1`'s deferred object is resolved. If the anonymous function is moved to after `doTask2`:

```
$.when(init()).then(doTask1).then(doTask2).done(function() { 
       console.log("new synchronous function"); 
   }).done(doLast);
```

then the anonymous function and the `doLast` function will both run when the deferred object returned from `doTask2` finishes.

Comment: Not working this...also the problem with this is that there are a lot of functions/callbacks nested...

Comment: see here more detailed: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/unwinding-promises-and-their-handlers-asp-net-mvc-and-jquery

Comment: What is it that is not working? I tried a  variation on this with only a single deferred object and chained then calls (similar to @KevinB's suggestion) and that works.

Comment: @user1624552 I've updated the answer, I forgot that you need to call the initial function passed and that it's result is what get's passed to the "done" functions.

Comment: Ok, maybe i have not tested well. If you put console.log('something') within each when's function, done's function and within each doTaskX, are console.logs printed in the console in order ?

Comment: The functions get called in the order they are registered on the deferred object. I've added console.log's to the last example as well, so you can just bring up the dev console when on the jQuery site and try it :)

Comment: I have checked your example in jsfiddle.that is because you have synchronous tasks so they are executed in order and the messages are displayed in order.Imagine in each of your tasks,apart from displaying messages to console,you do some asynchronous subtasks served as deferreds,then the behaviour you'll see is that things are not in order due to those asynchronous subtasks within taskA/B,this is my problem.So how can i call to this main tasksA/B in order $.when({count: 0}).done(init).done(taskA).done(taskB).done(ultimateTask); get executed all synchronous so messages are displayed ordered

Comment: For example in my case, message within ultimateTask, is printed before message within taskA when taskA is an asynchronous task that serves asynchronous subtasks as deferred so in order. How can I make the call to taskA to be treated synchronous so next taskB, ultimateTask not continue until taskA finishes? I can set  $.ajaxSetup({ async: false }); for taskA and taskB in a global way, then it works but.... it is blocking and i want it to be non-blocking! :(

Comment: @user1624552 I updated the answer to show how to accomplish what you are describing using `then` and Deferred objects. Does this solve your issue?

Comment: Not working.... :( please, see all my code in below link, so you can see my code. Execution starts when a submitButton is clicked on, the function DoAllTasks is launched, big functions are Task1 and Task2, those are asynchronous, have subtasks that are executed in order as deferred. See it please: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/process-tasks-in-order

Comment: Taking into account that task1 and task2 are asynchronous, how to make main code that when calling task1 and task2 to wait until they finish in order to continue executing below code but in a non-blocking way?

Comment: I think in this particular case, taking into account the task1 and task2 are asynchronous, it is better to use a $().queue instead, then queue all tasks there even init and doLast.

Comment: @user1624552 I think the problem in your code on the jquery forum is: `$.when(initialize()).then(initiate()).then(wtgs()).then(finalize()).done(terminate());` Note that in my example I'm passing the **functions** to `deffered.then()`. You are calling `initiate()`, `wtgs()`, `finalize()` and `terminate()` and passing the **result** of those functions as arguments to `deffered.then()`. Using a queue would of course be another way to go :)